# Count query doesn't work in store procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to select no of rows returned by select statement, but it returns 0, otherwise if I run simple count query, then it returns no of records being found WHY doesn't SP work for me ???

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

    CREATE PROCEDURE GetUser_Pwd
      @EmplID char,
      @EmplPwd varchar(50)

    As  
    BEGIN

        -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
        -- interfering with SELECT statements.
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        -- Insert statements for procedure here
        Declare @No_Rows int
        Select No_Rows= count(*) from HrEmployee where EmplID = @EmplID AND PassWord = @EmplPwd
        Return @No_Rows
    END
    GO
```

This return 0,

```
Exec GetUser_Pwd 1, 1234
```

This returns 1

```
select count(*) from HrEmployee where EmplID = 1 AND PassWord = 1234
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `RETURN @No_Rows` write `SELECT @No_Rows`.

**RETURN** statement is used for Functions .
For Stored Procedure, **RETURN** statement is used if you are using **OUTPUT** paramater.

[**Read here**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188655.aspx) on how to retrieve result from stored procedure

```
    Declare @No_Rows int
    Select @No_Rows= count(*) from HrEmployee where EmplID = @EmplID AND PassWord = @EmplPwd
    Select @No_Rows
```

Comment: done,  actually i have declared char(8) for EmplID but i was passing simply 1, but when i transformed char to int then it worked

Answer (score 1):

You will need to declare an OUTPUT variable. Try this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetUser_Pwd
  @EmplID char,
  @EmplPwd varchar(50),
  @No_Rows int OUTPUT

As  
BEGIN

    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    Select @No_Rows= count(*) 
    from HrEmployee 
    where EmplID = @EmplID AND PassWord = @EmplPwd
    RETURN
END
GO
```

Now, use the following to call the procedure

```
-- Declare the variable to receive the output value of the procedure.
DECLARE @No_Rows int;
-- Execute the procedure and save the output value in the variable @No_Rows
EXECUTE GetUser_Pwd @EmpId = '1',@EmplPwd='1234',@No_Rows=@No_Rows OUTPUT;
-- Display the value returned by the procedure.
PRINT 'Number of rows matching the criteria is ' + 
    convert(varchar(10),@No_Rows);
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

CREATE PROCEDURE GetUser_Pwd
  @EmplID char,
  @EmplPwd varchar(50)

As
BEGIN

```
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
Declare @No_Rows int
Select @No_Rows= count(*) from HrEmployee where EmplID = @EmplID AND PassWord = @EmplPwd
Return @No_Rows
```

END
GO
/*Calling Like ...*/
DECLARE @x INT 
EXEC @x = GetUser_Pwd @EmplID=1,@EmplPwd=1
SELECT @x